# How this regular expression is working

Tags: regex, shell

I found a script which has the following snippet:-

```
userid=`expr "\`id\`" : ".*uid=[0-9]*(\(.[0-9a-z]*\)) .*"`
```

It returns the userid.

When i tried to learn how it is doing:-

```
#id
#uid=11008(adilm) gid=1200(cvs),1400(build)
```

So I realized that (.[0-9a-z]*) is matching the userid. But if I placed like below:

```
#userid=`expr "uid=11008(ADILM) gid=1200(cvs),1400(build)" : ".*uid=[0-9]*(\(.[0-9a-z]*\)) .*"`
#echo $userid
ADILM
```

It works. As per my understanding '.' is matching to ADILM. But when i removed '.' like below:-

```
#userid=`expr "uid=11008(ADILM) gid=1200(cvs),1400(build)" : ".*uid=[0-9]*(\([0-9a-z]*\)) .*"`
#echo $userid
ADILM
```

It still works how? We have only provided lowercase letters but its still working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The subexpression `(\(.[0-9a-z]*\))` matches a group containing the brackets plus the user id.
- The dot inside this regex matches only the first character and all others need to be lowercase or numeric anyway.
- So obviously the regex here is not case sensitive (i option) per default. As your username is only `[a-z0-9]` it still matches.
- I don't think the dot makes sense. Are there any valid usernames not starting with a letter? The dot is here to make sure the username is at least one character long.
- Better might be `(\([0-9a-z]+\))` then.

Comment: How to make it case sensitive in expr?

Comment: @Peter i read that "The : operator can substitute for match." I tried `expr match "uid=11008(ADILM) gid=gid=1200(cvs),1400(build)" ".*uid=[0-9]*(\(.[0-9a-z]*\)) .*"` but its not working. It seems match is case sensitive but : is case insensitive (opposed to mentioned in man page and guides)

Comment: Has to be something like that. I don't know shell that well.

Answer (score 0):

this will not explain the regex, but alternative ways to get your id.

```
$ id -u -n

$ id|sed 's/uid=[0-9]*(//;s/).*//'
```